# change select values with id that has brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has lets say 3 items with a qty select element.

```
$someArray = array(
  '1',
  '2',
  '3'
);

foreach($someArray as $k => $v) {
  echo "<td>Qty</td>
                       <td><select class='qty' name='" . $v . "[qty]' id='" . $v . "[qty]'>";
  for ($a = 0; $a <= 5; $a++) {
    echo "<option value='" . $a . "'>" . $a . "</option>";
  }

  echo "</select></td>";
}
```

now in jquery, i want to make it so if you change the qty of any element, it changes all the elements of class qty to the selected value. I do not know what $v will equal, this is a dynmaic key of a db query result.

jquery

```
$('.qty').change(function() {
  var newQty = $(this).val();
  $.each($('.qty'), function() {
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(thisId+newQty);
    $('#'+thisId).val(newQty);
  });
});
```

the alert reads correct  (1[qty]1,  2[qty]1  ,3[qty]1),  however the select values are not changed by the next line.  The brackets in the element id messing things up. how can i adjust?

Comment: When asking a question, please take 3 minutes to tidy your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your IDs need brackets in them, but do this instead:

```
$('.qty').change(function(){
        var newQty = $(this).val();
        $('.qty').val(newQty);
});
```

The class selector will apply it to all elements that are of that class, no need for the each.

Comment: I was making this way more complicated then it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the issue is with the id. It might be easier to get rid of the brackets in your case however you can selected them by escaping the bracket.

Or you can do something ugly like:

`var thisId = $(this).attr('id').replace(']', '\\]').replace('[', '\\['));`